# Reload application.properties using @RefreshScope from spring.config.location

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

In my earlier set up, I was building my spring boot app as a WAR, extracting the contents of WAR and then running the application as

```
java -cp "location of application.properties" "Boot class"
```

I have spring cloud starter and actuator dependencies which allowed me to dynamically reload any changes made in application.properties using @RefreshScope annotation and /actuator/refresh end point.

But then I had to change the spring boot app build to generate a fat JAR instead which meant I had to start the application as below -

```
java -jar "my jar file" --spring.config.location=file:/"location of application.properties"
```

After doing this I am no longer able to reload application.properties changes dynamically using the same steps as above. A reload seems to trigger reexecution of the logic specified in @bean method annotated with @RefreshScope but old values from application.properties are being used.

I am using `@Autowired org.springframework.core.env.Environment` to access the properties.

Please help advise if there is anything that can be done to allow @RefreshScope and /actuator/refresh combination to work as expected in this scenario (java -jar)

Regards,
Jacob

Comment: Why change from classpath to `--spring.config.location=file...`?

Comment: Hi Spencer I think with -jar option -classpath will not work

Comment: Can you tell me why not? Have you tried it?

Comment: Hi Spencer, when we use -jar option, any paths mentioned as part of -classpath/-cp argument are ignored. I tried java -cp "location of application.properties" -jar "jar file". It does not read the application.properties. Anyway I found the reason why --spring.config.location was not working. There was an extra space I had accidentally added before --spring.config.location which was causing issue. Once i removed that space, reload is happening fine. Thanks again for your inputs.